# Slack app giving error when adding a incoming webbook

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am running into an issue a slack app I am working with. I created a slack app, had it approved from the slack admin and then tried to create an incoming webbook. But every time I try to create the webhook, I get the following error

```
This app is requesting permission to install a bot on your workspace, but it’s not currently configured with a bot. Please contact the developer to resolve this issue.
```

I tired to create the same app in a workspace I own and it worked perfectly. I am not sure if this is an access issue ? as the app has already been approved by the admin when I requested it.

Answer (score 9):

Had the same problem because the app name contains a ":" char.

Go to you app settings > Basic Information > Display Information

And set the app name with only alphanum chars.

Comment: This resolved the issue for me, as well as disabling incoming webhooks and then enabling it again.

Answer (score 4):

Incoming webhooks are attached to bots. You'll have to go to the **App Home** section of your configuration dashboard and make sure to configure a bot name before you can install the app. You shouldn't run into errors after that!

Comment: Same problem here, even after adding a bot name.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough reputation to add it as a comment but I run into a similar situation as Nurza described in his reply.

Created an app in Slack with the name X+X_build_alerts and then changed to XXXX (only letters) but it didn't helped.

to make things work I was required to delete the app entirely and start from scratch giving it an alphanum chars only name.

Only after that I was able to proceed further.
It seems like if the name of the app is wrong from the beginning it creates and identifier and changing the name afterwards would not make effect.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue occurred with an app that was started from scratch using the "Build apps from scratch" method and the app's name contained characters that were not alphanumeric.

Both the App Display Name and the Default Username fields were empty in the App Home section. After filling in these two fields, the installation was successful.